# VB.NET: Comparing an object to a string literal

Tags: vb.net

This might just be a matter of taste, but I'm wondering if there's a "recommended" way to compare a variable of type `Object` (which might be `Nothing` or have a different dynamic type than `String`) to a string literal in VB.NET.

The following options obviously won't work:

1. `If myObject = "Hello World" Then ...` -- won't compile
2. `If myObject Is "Hello World" Then ...` -- tests for reference equality, which is just wrong
3. `If myObject.Equals("Hello World") Then ...` -- throws an exception if myObject is Nothing
4. `If DirectCast(myObject, String) = "Hello World" Then ...` -- throws an exception if myObject is not a string

Thus, the only (simple, single-expression) solution I could find is to use

```
If "Hello World".Equals(myObject) Then ...
```

which looks a bit clumsy to me. Did I miss any obvious alternative, other than doing type checks or explicit checks for `Nothing`?

(Of course, we're talking about `Option Strict On`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
If TryCast(myObject, String) = "Hello World" Then
```

If `myObject` is not a String, then `TryCast` will return `Nothing`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.Equals("Hello World", myObject) -or-
Object.Equals(myObject, "Hello World")
```

The former will unconditionally call "Hello World".Equals, while the latter will call MyObject.Equals if MyObject is non-null, or else return false (since the quoted literal isn't null).

Note that with properly-designed objects, both of the above should be equivalent, but it's possible that MyObject could have an Equals method which returns True when compared to the string "Hello World"; if it does, the second statement would return True while the first would return False.

Comment: Are you sure? According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx), `Object.Equals(obj1, obj2)` just checks for reference equality (which is unsuitable for string comparison). Yes, it mentions overriding this functionality in derived classes, but that doesn't make sense because static methods cannot be overridden...

Comment: If obj1 and obj2 are non-null, Object.Equals will use *virtual* method obj1.Equals(obj2).

Comment: @supercat: Indeed, you are right, I just verified it with Reflector. I don't think I'll use it though, since it's not properly documented (so I cannot rely on this behavior according to the "design by contract" principle), but it's good to know nevertheless. +1

Comment: @Heinzi: Object.Equals is explicitly documented to work by calling the virtual Equals method on Object1 when appropriate.  That's not to say that you can't do better by using Object.Equals on the string you know isn't null.

Comment: @supercat: Can you show me a link to that explicit documentation?

Comment: @Heinzi: I read it in a printed book, which I don't have handy. The msdn Object.Equals(Object, Object) page, however, does contain a demo that shows that comparisons to null are permitted; it also tests two strings, but as coded doesn't ensure that they're not reference-equal (so they probably are). I did get the sequence slightly wrong, though: It first tests for reference equality (if equal, return True).  Then it tests if Object1 is null.  If so, return False. Otherwise, return Object1.Equals(Object2) [the case where Object2 is null and Object1 not should be handled in Object1.Equals].

Answer (score 2):

How about the shared function on the string class

```
If String.Compare(Trycast(myObject, String), "Hello World") = 0 Then...
```

This will also return inequality if myObject is Nothing or is not a string.

Comment: Thanks. Does using `String.Compare(...) = 0` have any advantages as compared to Guido's solution?